# Passwordless аутентификация

Tags: безопасность, аутентификация

Есть мобильное приложение, где логин должен быть осуществлен через passwordless аутентификацию (телефон и код из СМС). Подскажите, как реилизовать данный флоу на бэкенде? Как избежать брутфорса кода? И т.д.?

Есть готовое решение у сервиса auth0, но оно по ряду причин не подходит.

Comment: Ограничивайте время действия и количество попыток ввода кода. Соответственно на бакенде записиваете и проверяете произошедшие попытки ввода кода.

Comment: @Mike кроме ограничения количества попыток, злоумышленник может заново присылать номер телефона и снова отправлять код до истечения количетва попыток

Comment: Не может. таймаут в течение которого должен быть введен код стоит использовать и для проверки того, что смс уже отправлялась и не позволять в течение этого таймаута отправлять код повторно на тот же номер. А еще злоумышленник может заддосить вас запросами со случайными номерами телефона и у вас быстро закончатся деньги на СМС-сервисе. Так что как минимум стоит ограничивать количество запросов в единицу времени с одного ip. Но конечно от ботнета это не защитит

Comment: У нас в мобильное приложение например дополнительно зашит клиентский сертификат, который используется при всех https запросах к API серверу. Так что без серьезного разбора приложения и вытаскивания сертификата подделать запросы к серверу, а следовательно и начать запрашивать СМС на тонны номеров сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Основная идея

Возможно, Вашим решением будет создание в хранилище пары "ключ-значение".
В качестве ключа берется id сессии, в качестве значения - сгенерированный код.

- После отправки запроса на регистрацию/аутентификацию, клиенту для указанного номера генерируется код
- затем пара ключ-значение (id_сессии-смс_код) сохраняется и идет отправка этого кода по СМС на указанный номер.
- Пользователь его получает, вводит, далее вы сверяете введенный код со значением, лежащим по ключу сессии, и если оно верно - аутентифицируете его

После этого **обязательно** удаляйте эту пару, чтобы не было возможности воспользоваться ей второй раз. Вообще необходимо указывать **время жизни** этой пары, например, одна минута, тогда перебрать такой пароль вряд ли удастся - не хватит времени.

Хранить все это дело лучше не в базе данных, а в более подходящем для этого месте - в оперативной памяти. (можно использовать для этого [memcached](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) или тот же [redis](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis))
Потому что во-первых, быстрые мелкие запросы к хранилищу будут гораздо эффективнее,чем запросы к БД, так как первые заточены именно под это.
Во-вторых, время жизни легко указывается штатными средствами этих продуктов.

### Возможные проблемы

Создавайте в качестве ключа **именно сессию, а не телефон** пользователя.
В случае указания телефона ключом, идет сокращение необходимых для взлома полей. Например, зная телефон пользователя, остается только подобрать код из четырех цифр. Хоть это и вряд ли получится сделать из-за времени жизни, предположим, взломщику повезло и он подобрал код с первой попытки. Тогда он войдет без проблем.

В случае же с сессией, необходимо:

- знать номер телефона
- иметь к нему доступ для получения кода
- иметь доступ к конкретному устройству, чтобы ввести этот код

### Примечания

Возможно, Вам и не придется создавать такую пару ключа-значения вручную. В большинстве фреймворком можно несложно задать какой-нибудь ключ для текущей сессии. 
делается это как-то типа

```
request.session.set('key', 'value')
```

а проверяется

```
if request.session.get('key') == value:
    do_stuff
```

Погуглите Ваш случай. Если такая встроенная возможность имеется, то просто в качестве ключа укажите его предназначение - 'auth_code', а в качестве значения - тот самый код

Comment: Если все еще боитесь, то можно, помимо времени жизни, наложить ограничение на количество попыток ввода кода, по исчерпании которого высылается новый код

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! На ваш взгляд при stateless полходе допустим такой вариант: пользователь отправлят номер телефона -> бэкенд генерирует guid, код, сохраняет в редис, отправляет смс с кодом, в ответ клиенту отправляет guid -> клиент вместе с кодом отправляет также полученный guid?

Comment: Еще как вариант - не хранить код и guid. Код сделать через totp, а клиенту отдавать jwt

Comment: Это более безопасно, но менее человечно =), на мой взгляд. Думаю, люди привыкли получать в качестве кодов подтверждения 4-8 цифр, а не строку символов. Ну и как минимум дешевле. Все-таки за длину сообщения придется платить

Comment: в смс так и будет 408 цифр, а в ответ http-запроса, когда присылается телефон, отдастся jwt. как вы считаете?

Comment: Звучит хорошо. Это предотвратит CSRF